# Package that contains square epsilon

Tags: packages, greek

I am looking for an edgy/square epsilon like in the following, but haven't been able to find something.
Can somebody point me to a package that provides it?

[image: Square epsilon]

Comment: is that an epsilon? where does the image come from, if you have the pdf, you can see what font it is,

Comment: Its from this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.03871.pdf. I don't know if it really is an epsilon. How do I find that out in a PDF?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: but its on arxiv so even easier as you have the tex source

Answer (score 8):

You just download the source, which is a tarball, and extract it.

In the file `arxiv_new.tex` you find

```
\newcommand{\sqin}{%
  \mathrel{\vphantom{\sqsubset}\text{%
    \mathsurround=0pt
    \ooalign{$\sqsubset$\cr$-$\cr}%
  }}%
}
```

[image]

There is actually no need for the `\vphantom`, in this case, and with `\mathpalette` it's slightly more efficient.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sqin}{}% just in case
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sqin}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\sq@in\relax}}
\newcommand{\sq@in}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\sqsubset$\cr$\m@th#1-$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$(w,I')\sqin N^{\Delta}(v,I)$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works for me. How to you find the source? I'm new to arxiv. Do I need to alter the URL I posted? I guess you got it from here: https://arxiv.org/format/1605.03871

Comment: @Morinator Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether my answer exactly solves the problem (sure egreg's does) because I didn't check how it looks in a MWE and if you'd obtain an exact reproduction of the original.

It seems to be the unicode character "U+22FF Z NOTATION BAG MEMBERSHIP", so you can copy/paste it (here you are: ⋿), find a font that has it, and compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. I don't know if you need a *math* font that has it, since I never use mathmode and know almost nothing of its peculiarities with respect to fonts and unicode characters.

For the record: I used the "table de caractères" (character lookup table) function of my Linux Mint (should be there in many Linux flavours), I looked up the meaning in the linked article from arxiv (it says *temporal membership*), then I looked for these keywords, didn't find anything, so I reduced my search to just *membership* and bingo.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The ⋿ symbol is `\bagmember` in `stix`, `stix2` and `unicode-math`.  The OpenType math fonts XITS Math and STIX Two Math both contain it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\pagestyle{empty}

\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{STIX Two Text}[Scale = 1.0]
  \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[Scale = MatchUppercase]
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{stix2}
\fi

\begin{document}
\[ (w,I')\bagmember N^{\increment}(v,I) \]
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX Two sample]

In `unicode-math`, you can take this one symbol from STIX Two even if you are using a different math font.

```
\setmathfont[range={\bagmember}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{STIX Two Math}
```

With legacy font packages, the exact commands you would use for this vary from font to font.  The fastest way to figure them out is to open `stix2.sty` or `stix.sty`, figure out the minimal set of commands needed to define that symbol, and copy them.

You could also try loading your font packages of choice over `stix2` or `stix`, which should leave any commands defined only in those packages untouched.  Legacy LaTeX limits you to 16 math alphabets, however, so you could easily run out that way.